# Jail folder SFTP for a single user

Tags: permissions, ssh, webserver, sftp

Is it possibile to configure a particular user to be jailed in a particular folder when connected to SFTP through SSHD?
I need to give SFTP access to an user to upload and manage a website in /var/www/mywebsite but I don't want to let him browser outside that folder.

I have tried the Chroot setting of SSHD but as far as I understand I cannot configure a single user. BTW the folder is not the user home directory.

Comment: Sorry but you do not let users access anything in /var/www/. That is asking for problems. What you do is let them upload to a dedicated partition or directory and then let the system copy those files over to /var/www/ That way you have full control and can create a procedure where you do or do not accept something. That also directly solves your problem.

Comment: This is not what I asked. And the scenario you described is not suitable for me.

Comment: That is why it is a comment and not an answer and it is based on my experience using Linux and webservers  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use scponly shell for the user. It will install two new shells on your system.

1. Scponly. Allows only scp ans sftp access. But to the entire system.
2. Scponlyc. The same but also jails a user to the login folder as the top level.

https://www.howtoforge.com/using-scponly-to-allow-scp-sftp-logins-and-disable-ssh-logins-on-debian-squeeze